# Printing Hello World in different colors in terminal

Tags: c, linux, colors

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    printf("\033[0;30Hello world!\n");
    printf("\033[0;31Hello world!\n");
    printf("\033[0;32Hello world!\n");
    printf("\033[0;33Hello world!\n");
    printf("\033[0;34Hello world!\n");
    printf("\033[0;35Hello world!\n");
    printf("\033[0;36Hello world!\n");
    printf("\033[0;37Hello world!\n");
}
```

I feel ashamed for posting that, but I have completely no idea about C and when I tried to do this with loop it always threw some errors.

I tried something like that:

```
for(int i=30; i<=37; i++){
   char* color = "\033[0;"+itoa(i);
   printf("%s Hello world", color);
}
```

And well, tons of errors, like I'm trying to concatenate string with int or somethink. I also tried strcat, type casting, giving all to printf and setting %d instead of variable and some others things. I'm working on Virtual Machine and it's really hard and I need it fast, counting on your help.

BTW: are there any more colors than 30-37? I know you can make it bold with 1 instead of 0 etc.

Comment: Answers are fine, but keep in mind not all terminals are the same, so hardcoding escape sequences *could* be a bad idea. It's better to use a library ... eg `termcap`, `terminfo` or even better `(n)curses`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
for(int i=30; i<=37; i++){
   char color[20];
   snprintf(color, sizeof(color), "\033[%dm", i);
   printf("%s Hello world\n", color);
}
```

or even simpler, but the previous code is more readable

```
for(int i=30; i<=37; i++){
   printf("\033[%dmHello world\n", i);
}
```

There are several problems in your attempt:

```
for(int i=30; i<=37; i++){
   char* color = "\033[0;"+itoa(i);   << - you can't add strings with '+'
                                         - itoa requires 3 parameters
                                         - you forgot the 'm' at the end of the
                                         - escape sequence
   printf("%s Hello world", color);
}
```

Untested code, but it should give you at least an idea.

Comment: Isn't snprintf specified only in C99 ? **sprintf** should be ok.

Answer (score 3):

To print Hello word in different colors you can use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define KBCK  "\x1B[30m"    /* Black */
#define KRED  "\x1B[31m"    /* Red */
#define KGRN  "\x1B[32m"    /* Green */
#define KYEL  "\x1B[33m"    /* Yellow */
#define KBLU  "\x1B[34m"    /* Blue */
#define KMAG  "\x1B[35m"    /* Magenta */
#define KCYN  "\x1B[36m"    /* Cyan */
#define KWHI  "\x1B[37m"    /* White */
#define RESET "\033[0m"


int main(void){
    printf(KBCK "Hello world! - in Black\n"RESET);
    printf(KRED "Hello world! - in Red\n"RESET);
    printf(KGRN "Hello world! - in Green\n"RESET);
    printf(KYEL "Hello world! - in Yellow\n"RESET);
    printf(KBLU "Hello world! - in Blue\n"RESET);
    printf(KMAG "Hello world! - in Magenta\n"RESET);
    printf(KCYN "Hello world! - in Cyan\n"RESET);
    printf(KWHI "Hello world! - in White\n"RESET);

    return 0;
}
```

Any way you do have a lot of question there, you should ask separately all of them.

You can take a look on [ANSI color codes](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)

As Felix Palmer said, you can use ncurses:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_in_middle(WINDOW *win, int starty, int startx, int width, char *string){ 
    size_t length=0;
    int x, y;
    float temp;

    if(win == NULL)
        win = stdscr;
    getyx(win, y, x);
    if(startx != 0)
        x = startx;
    if(starty != 0)
        y = starty;
    if(width == 0)
        width = 80;

    length = strlen(string);
    temp = (float)(width - (int)length)/ 2;
    x = startx + (int)temp;
    mvwprintw(win, y, x, "%s", string);
    refresh();
}

int main(void){
    initscr();          /* Start curses mode        */
    if(has_colors() == FALSE)
    {   endwin();
        printf("Your terminal does not support color\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    start_color();          /* Start color          */
    init_pair(1, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    print_in_middle(stdscr, LINES / 2, 0, 0, "This text should be Yellow");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
        getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

You can change the Color by changing the following:

```
init_pair(1, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLACK);
```

Available colors are:

> ```
> COLOR_BLACK   0
> COLOR_RED     1
> COLOR_GREEN   2
> COLOR_YELLOW  3
> COLOR_BLUE    4
> COLOR_MAGENTA 5
> COLOR_CYAN    6
> COLOR_WHITE   7
> ```